# ruby on rails 3 date attribute with date_select not being assigned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a view with the following:

```
=f.date_select :start_date, { :start_year => 1990, :end_year => Time.now.year, :discard_day => true, :prompt => true, :order => [ :month, :year] }
```

Where my :start_year is an attribute on my ActiveRecord model called WorkHistory.
And in my controller I have:

```
@work_history = WorkHistory.new(params[:work_history])
```

The start_date never gets set and is always `nil`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are there any attr_protected calls in your WorkHistory model? Also, post a request log so we can look at what is being posted from the form.

Comment: I just noticed this warning:
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: start_date(3i), start_date(2i), start_date(1i)
But I don't declare it as protected... or is it protected by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I needed to add `attr_accessible` for it to work.